# Is there any way to get the User ID of the user visiting Facebook App without any authentication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth

Let me make it clear, I want to welcome the user visiting my facebook app. So that I can refer his name in my facebook application. I don't need any other permissions or I don't have any other operation to perform. I just want to fetch his name thats all.For this simple thing the facebook app authentication precess is an overhead. Do they left any other option??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook app without prompted authentication](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7520300/facebook-app-without-prompted-authentication)

Comment: Please check my answer above. This applies for the user id and name!

Comment: okie..i give up :(.thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no option of doing so using Facebook SDK or Graph API without authentication of user.